# Compiling error with Buildroot 2017.08

Tags: python, sqlite, cross-compiling, buildroot

I have a customized python packet, it imports sqlite3 in setup.py.
When compiling with Buildroot 2017.02 (command: make clean all), no problem.
But I got compiling error after updating Buildroot to 2017.08 (command: make clean all).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    import sys, glob, sqlite3
ImportError: No module named sqlite3
```

Following is the list when I find "sqlite*" in //buildroot/output/host/, it has sqlite3 packet in host folder (2017.08):

```
./arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/pkgconfig/sqlite3.pc
./arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/python2.7/sqlite3
./arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/share/man/man1/sqlite3.1
./arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/bin/sqlite3
./arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h
./arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/include/sqlite3.h
./lib/pkgconfig/sqlite3.pc
./share/man/man1/sqlite3.1
./bin/sqlite3
./include/sqlite3ext.h
./include/sqlite3.h
```

Every hint is very appreciated.

Comment: Which Python interpreter did you use to get this error? Path?

Comment: You can clone the Buildroot repository https://git.busybox.net/buildroot/ and diff the two tags/versions to see what has changed.

Comment: Python 2.7; /output/host/usr/bin/python

Comment: I compared sqlite packet, not too much difference, and there're hundred of commits, I don't know which part related to this issue. Thank you very much.

Comment: `/output/host/usr/bin/python`! Is it a link to `./arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/bin/python`? Because you should use this one.

Comment: Sort it out. Enable sqlite in python host config

Answer (score 0):

This should never have worked to begin with. host-python is built without sqlite3 module in Buildroot (cfr. the `--disable-sqlite3` in `HOST_PYTHON_CONF_OPTS`). So it shouldn't be possible to import the sqlite3 module from a `setup.py` script. This `--disable-sqlite3` option has been there already for a long time.

One thing that changed iin 2017.08 is that `$(TARGET_DIR)/usr/lib/python$(PYTHON_VERSION_MAJOR)/site-packages` was removed from `PYTHON_PATH`. So perhaps you previously had a sqlite3 module installed there, and it happened to work.

The easiest solution for you is probably to change the `--disable-sqlite3` into an `--enable-sqlite3` and make host-python depend on host-sqlite3.

Comment: I --enable-sqlite3 and make host-python depend on host-sqlite3 for long time. This time, when I merged to new version, I made a mistake and override this config.